# CommandButton outside of a form: Is it possible to Post a Form by an Id?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a CommandButton (PrimeFaces 3.0.1), that is not in a Form-Tag. Is there a way to reference a form via it's Id or something, so that the Button can post a Form even when it's not a child-element of that Form?
I did'nt find any apropriate in the specs...

The Button currently looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{messages['000.label.ok']}"
         oncomplete="w00001.hide()" type="submit" 
                 action="cancel"
         ajax="false" immediate="true" />
```

After pressing the Button JSF forwards to another page, that is mapped by the key "cancel".

Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call another form from the command button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766255/call-another-form-from-the-command-button)

Answer (score 4):

*edit1*
So what you want to do is submit a form, then redirect. As said before, commandButton has to be inside a form if you want to use it for submit, but it doesn't has to be the **same** form. You can wrap a second form around commandButton, and still use it to submit the values of your first form.

```
        <h:form id="form_test">
            <!-- values of this form will be submitted -->
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="cancel" action="#{yourBean.cancelFlow}"
                process="form_test @this" ajax="false" />
        </h:form>
```

the Method in *YourBean.java* could look like this (assuming your cancelpage.xhtml is in the package *your.package*)

```
public String cancelFlow() {
    // do something with form data

    return "/your/package/cancelpage?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

You could also redirect programmatically, using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect`

Comment: Unfortunatly, I think, this is not why I need... I need a submit

Comment: This indeed submits the first form (input type of commandButton defaults to "submit"). Maybe i misunderstood what you want, can you post your source-code?

Comment: I've edited the problem-description. I need a way to send this "cancel"-token to the Server so that JSF can redirect me to another page

Comment: Thank you for your help! In the end I was able to set the button in the form, so my problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766570/3568831 You cannot process another from by a submit of one form you should use `<p:remoteCommand />`  as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24731901/3568831)
and also with this [link](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5666&sid=df0adc945a8dfd5e75ebfcbc71efe282&start=10) to see an example