# Delete Rows Using Checkbox in JSF

Tags: jsf, ejb, rows

I am trying to delete multiple rows of employee data using checkboxes. However i am having a hard time finding a way to do this. The following is some code:

DeleteEmployees.xhtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<f:loadBundle basename="resources.application" var="msg"/>

<head>
    <title><h:outputText value="#{msg.welcomeTitle}" /></title>
</head>
<h:body>
    <h:dataTable value="#{empController.list}" var="emp" border="2">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="First Name"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.firstName}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Last Name"/>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{emp.lastName}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Email"/>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{emp.email}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Phone"/>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{emp.phone}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Hire Date"/>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{emp.hireDate}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Manager ID"/>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{emp.managerId}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Department ID"/>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{emp.departmentId}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                 <h:form>
                     <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{empController.checked[emp.id]}"/>    
                </h:form>
             </f:facet>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton value="Delete Employees" action="#{empController.delEmp}"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

In my Managed bean i have this method in order to delete the ID. However the objects are not being deleted. I need some guidance here thank you!

```java
public void delEmp(){
    list = em.getAllEmployees();

    for(Employee e : list){
        if(checked.get(e.getId())){
            em.deleteEmployee(e.getId());
        }
    }
    checked.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `h:commandButton` is not nested within the `h:form`. It needs to be nested for the form data to submit. Note that this is not a JSF limitation, but an HTML limitation.

#### See also

- [Call another form from the command button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766570/201891)

Comment: also, use `h:head` instead of `head`.